# Method to call on mail object to deliver a text format mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I would like to know what message I can call on `Mail` object in a console to deliver a mail in text format.

I am debugging my Mailers, and typing `m.deliver!` in the console, and opening the email in my email account. This works fine, but it only generates and delivers `html` format email. I don't know what `text` format email looks like.

I know that there are gems such as `letter_opener` but I rarely change my Mailer codes, and want to know if there is a method I can use it console to force text format upon delivery of a mail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails renders and delivers all the available formats. Your mail client shows you the HTML version by default, but it can open the text version too. For example, in Gmail choose "Message text garbled". More info: http://www.mailermailer.com/support/knowledgebase/sending/kb/495